# expired US passport and Nexus only do I need a valid us passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-citizens

My US passport has expired  I have applied for new nexus card  it expires in Mar. 2019  Is a nexus card enough to get back in the US?

Comment: Will you be entering by air, land or sea?  From what country?

Comment: Where are you travelling from? The US can choose to let you in with whatever documents it wants, but most other countries will require you to have a passport to get on an international flight.

Answer (score 3):

1. A US citizen cannot be denied entry at a US border.
2. A US citizen is required (in most cases) to have a valid passport to enter. However, rule #1 trumps rule#2: they will eventually let you in with an expired passport, but it may take a while and they may give some grief.
3. No airline will let you board a flight to the US without a valid passport, because of rule #2. They don't care about rule #1. Getting to a border will be tricky.
4. Somewhat different rules apply for entering from Canada and for land and sea borders.

Comment: This answer is not necessarily correct. A NEXUS card can be used to fly from Canada

Comment: Hence I wrote: "different rules apply for entering from Canada". Is that not clear enough ?

Comment: @Hilmar it's perfectly clear, but perhaps not precise or detailed enough, especially since the question concerns someone with a nexus card.

Comment: Could a U.S. embassy in the country where the OP currently is be of any help?

Comment: Historically, entering from Canada occurred inside Canada, before boarding the flight, which solved a lot of problems. US Citizens can be strongly encouraged not to enter due to FATCA considerations. so 1. is not hard and fast for citizens entering for the first time.

Comment: @mckenzm Still works like that at Canada's 7 largest airports

Answer (score 2):

If you fly directly from Canada, or enter the US by land/sea, you can use your NEXUS card to enter the US.

Otherwise you need a valid US passport.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the safest way to get back home is to apply for an Emergency Passport.
[US Embassy Website](https://pl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/)
This is about US Embassy in Poland but I'm pretty sure it works the same way in every country. Check `Emergency Passport` section:

*The U.S. Embassy in Warsaw can issue emergency passports in certain limited circumstances. These passports have very restricted validity and are generally issued only to enable stranded citizens to return home. Persons who need emergency passports should apply during regular working hours and should follow the regular instructions for the type of passport that pertains to them. Provided that everything is in order emergency passports are issued within 1-2 hours, however in certain situations the waiting time may be longer.*